# Merging Excel-Files without reprocessing the content

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

I have a very complex Excel tool to analyze data. I want to enter raw-data into a separate sheet in this file using python. I tried this with openpyxl, but this was destroying my other sheets and diagrams because of unsupported functionalities of openpyxl. When saving, openpyxl is reprocessing all the datasheets.
Is there a way to just combine two excel files without this reprocessing? Or another tool allowing for opening a sheet and writing into this without the above mentioned problems? So basically just blindly taking a datasheet and copy that to another file without any changes in other datasheets and compatibility problems.

Comment: You might want to consider using the pandas library

Comment: The safest solution in your case would probably be to let Excel itself perform the copy operation. This can be automated by either a small VBA script, or a python script that commands Excel through COM interface (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44596301/7306999).

Comment: Use xlwings for this kind of thing.