# I want to copy one excel column data to another excel row data using python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx', sheet_name=None,header=None)
tester=dfs['Sheet1'].values.tolist()
keys = list(zip(*tester))[0]
seen = set()

seen_add = seen.add
keysu= [x for x in keys if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]
values = list(zip(*tester))[1]
a = np.array(values).reshape(int(len(values)/len(keysu)),len(keysu))
list1=[keysu]

for i in a:
    list1.append(list(i))

df=pd.DataFrame(list1)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx',index=False,header=False)
```

I want to copy one excel column data to another excel row data using python
want to execute and run

Comment: Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593705/how-to-copy-over-an-excel-sheet-to-another-workbook-in-python#44596301

Comment: add your error message