# How to copy data from One Excel sheet tab to another particular Workbook Tab Using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, export-to-excel, excel-automation

Can you please help me in copying data from a particular tab of excel sheet to another tab of excel sheet bearing the same name and data but in different workbook using Python.The workbook in which the data will be copied will also contain different tabs as well.Please find the attachment. Thank You in advance.

Need to copy this data to the sample sheet on the left:

[image: Need to copy this data to the sample sheet on the left]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy over an Excel sheet to another workbook in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593705/how-to-copy-over-an-excel-sheet-to-another-workbook-in-python)

Comment: It may be easier to copy the work book, since they both have the same name, data, and worksheets.

Comment: I am trying to automate it