# duplicating a workeet with the exact same style (formuls, formatting, values, etc)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Hi Im trying to duplicate a workeet in excel but i cant get it to duplicate the sheet with exact same style and formatting. Im using the following command. can someone provide some guidance please?

```
source = ws1
target = wb.copy_worksheet(source)
```

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593705/how-to-copy-over-an-excel-sheet-to-another-workbook-in-python

Comment: yes it doesnt carry over the style

Comment: Right click on the tab and use move/copy and check the box for a copy. Always duplicates correctly including the Solver settings.

Comment: This is part of an automation process, so trying to do this without opening excel

Comment: In the link @Victor provided there are 3 solutions. Solution 1 will only copy data only so is no good. Solution 3 using xlwings is probably the better to use. It will copy style and formatting within the same workbook, did you try that? If so what style did not copy?