# Load sheet in an excel file and save it to another different excel file

Tags: python, openpyxl, excel-automation

Using python 3, I'm trying to append a sheet from an existing excel file to another excel file.

I have conditional formats in this excel file so I can't just use pandas.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

final_wb = load_workbook("my_final_workbook_with_lots_of_sheets.xlsx")
new_wb = load_workbook("workbook_with_one_sheet.xlsx")

worksheet_new = new_wb['Sheet1']
final_wb.create_sheet(worksheet_new)

final_wb.save("my_final_workbook_with_lots_of_sheets.xlsx")
```

This code doesn't work because the `.create_sheet` method only makes a new blank sheet, I want to insert my `worksheet_new` that I loaded from the other file into the `final_wb`

Comment: You can't do it. Worksheets contain workbook-specific information that means that they cannot be copied or moved between workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

See this issue on openpyxl discussing this same feature: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/171/

It is not currently a builtin function of openpyxl, but that thread has some workarounds available that may suit your needs.

EDIT: Also found a likely duplicate question here: [Copy worksheet from one workbook to another one using Openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344041/copy-worksheet-from-one-workbook-to-another-one-using-openpyxl)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using [pandas.ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html), which also uses xlrd and openpyxl in the background:

I created two sample excel-files:

- `test1.xlsx`
- `test2.xlsx`

and append the first sheet of `test1.xlsx` to `test2.xlsx`:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                              

In [2]: from pandas import ExcelWriter                                                                   

In [3]: with ExcelWriter("test2.xlsx", mode="a") as writer: 
   ...:     df1 = pd.read_excel("test1.xlsx", sheet_name=0) 
   ...:     df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="New sheet name")
```

Important is the `mode="a"`, which toggles the append-mode.

Comment: sorry, i was jokingly referring to pandas as an actual bear. Like the animal. In my comment `bear == pandas`