# python program combine multiple excel files into one workbook with separate sheets

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to combine multiple excel workbooks into one workbook, with multiple sheets. The names and contents from original workbooks are maintained in the final workbook. eg. let say I have test1.xls(sheeta,sheetb), test2.xls(sheet1), test3.xls(sheet2). The final file output.xls(sheeta,sheetb,sheet1,sheet2). I have seen other similar posts here, but did not find to work for me. Some of them do not copy exact content of the sheet. I have pictures and data in each sheet.

Comment: What have you done this far and is there any error messages?

Comment: And is there any reason you want to do this in Python. If this is a real life problem, I'd look at Excel's built-in Visual Basic. Then you could do the same later on with macro-enabled Excel-file and you wouldn't need to install Python with Excel-library on your computer.  Looks a little bit like a homework for me though.

Comment: @ex4, what if Excel isn't installed on his system? But Visual Basic is also quite slow for a lot of things.

Comment: @CharlieClark it's feels unexpected situation that someone works with Excel files like this but doesn't have Excel. Possible of course. And yes, VB is awful to write and usually very slow. But it works with this kind of stuff.

Comment: There has been similar posting with good conversation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344041/copy-worksheet-from-one-workbook-to-another-one-using-openpyxl . So it seems that there is no simple way to do that. It's doable to copy data in cells anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy worksheet from one workbook to another one using Openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344041/copy-worksheet-from-one-workbook-to-another-one-using-openpyxl)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have VB code

Sub GetSheets()

Path = "C:\Users\ABC\"

Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

Do While Filename <> ""

Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Next Sheet

Workbooks(Filename).Close

Filename = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
but it adds multiple of same file sometimes and I have to manually delete those.

Comment: I tried following python code

import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import win32com.client as win32

path_read =r'C:/Users/ABC/'

excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()

for f in glob.glob(path_read + "/*.xls"):
    w = excel.Workbooks.Open(f) 
    w.Sheets(1).Copy(wb.Sheets(1))

wb.SaveAs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "CM.xlsx"))
excel.Application.Quit()

but it copies only the data, my excel sheets has pictures which are not copied.