# Append excel files using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Can use either of these not just pandas `import csv pandas  openpyxl import load_workbook openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter xlrd glob`

Want to combine multiple excel files:
I have tried this **simple**approach->

```
# collect excel content into list of dataframes
data = []
for excel_file in excel_files:
    data.append(pd.read_excel(excel_file, engine="openpyxl"))
    data.append(gapDf)

# concatenate dataframes horizontally
df = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
# save combined data to excel
df.to_excel(excelAutoNamed, index=False)
```

**Problem**
Above approach messes with the formatting of how the excel file initially was because it just adds everything to a dataframe list and appends it**
which gets rid of **column highlights**  ,**bolding**

**Instead** of converting them to df then concating, **how** to add multiple excel files to one workbook

**example** [image: excelFile with bolding and highlights (No DF Used)]

**Idea** keep track of the previous excel files last column b/c to leave some gap to write the next excel file on the workBook. (**quickNote**: trying a dynamic approach bc not all excel files have the same # of columns)

Comment: Do you have to use Python?

Comment: preferably @norie

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Based partially off *Oscar*'s answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68800310/3589122

```py
import openpyxl
from copy import copy
import os

# Tuple of filenames
filenames = ("spreadsheet1.xlsx", 
             "spreadsheet2.xlsx", 
             "spreadsheet3.xlsx", 
             "spreadsheet4.xlsx", 
            )

# Create a new workbook
new_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
new_ws = new_wb.active

# column_num is the next column number to be written to in the new spreadsheet
column_num = 1

# Read each workbook, and copy each column, cell by cell, to the new spreadsheet
for filename in filenames:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    ws = wb.active
    
    for column in ws.iter_cols():
        for cell in column:
            new_cell = new_ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=column_num, value=cell.value)  
            
            # Styles have to be manually copied
            if cell.has_style:
                new_cell.font = copy(cell.font)
                new_cell.border = copy(cell.border)
                new_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill)
                new_cell.number_format = copy(cell.number_format)
                new_cell.protection = copy(cell.protection)
                new_cell.alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
        
        # Preserve the same column width
        width = ws.column_dimensions[cell.column_letter].width
        new_ws.column_dimensions[new_cell.column_letter].width = width
        
        column_num += 1    

# Save the new workbook to disk
new_filename = "combined.xlsx"
new_wb.save(new_filename)

# Launch the new spreadsheet
os.startfile(new_filename)
```

Comment: This seems very intuative, I also have a few more questions in regards to approach, is there a medium of communication we could use? Slack, Discord, Not sure if SO has inbox for messaging options. I greatly appreciate your answer, PLease let me know @GordonAitchJay

Comment: No problemo. Try to start a chat with my here on SO https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3589122/gordonaitchjay. You might not be able to because of lack of reputation. I don't use Slack or Discord, so try Facebook messenger - gordonhj.

Comment: Hi man, I posted a question about layout and formatting: let me know if you have any intel @GordonAitchJay       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72651521/adding-a-title-using-python