# How to copy a worksheet from another workbook using Python (openpyxl)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I need to copy one worksheet to another one.
I have a workbook wb1, which has many sheets. Firstly, I activate it and then create a new sheet at the beginning as I need to put it there:

`import openpyxl`

`wb1= openpyxl.load_workbook(path_full_file)`

`sheet='current_date'`

`wb1.create_sheet(sheet, 0)`

It works fine, the sheet 'current date' is created at the beginning. Then I need to copy to this sheet information from wb2, which has only one sheet:

\open wb2

`wb2= openpyxl.load_workbook(path_to ).active`

\trying to copy sheet from wb2 to wb1

`wb1[sheet]=wb2`

The last row does not work as I get the error: "AttributeError: **setitem**".

Could you advise what to do?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy worksheet from one workbook to another one using openpyxl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344041/how-to-copy-worksheet-from-one-workbook-to-another-one-using-openpyxl)

Comment: It seems to be easier method without creating so many functions. I know how to duplicate sheet by "._add_sheet(...)", but it duplicates in the end instead of the beginning.

Comment: No, Openpyxl is not a must. I will read about Xlwings , thanks.

Comment: Xlwings works very slow, I do not see the reason. Openpyxl seems to be more preferable

Comment: If to do something like excel_from = openpyxl.load_workbook('w.xlsx').active
excel_from ._parent = w2
w2._add_sheet(excel_from ). Then the sheet will be added to the end, but how to put it at the beginning?

Comment: You can't do this and for good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following Xlwings code samples;

Example 1;
will open the workbook and copy the worksheet 'Sheet3' and place the copy before the first Sheet in the workbook i.e. the copied sheet is now the first sheet, and names the Sheet 'NewSheet'.
Then saves the workbook.
Example 2;
will copy the same sheet from workbook 1, 'excel_file.xlsx' to another workbook 2, 'new_excel_file.xlsx' as the first sheet and names the Sheet 'NewSheet'.
Takes around a second to run the code.

Example 1 copy sheet within the same workbook

```
import xlwings as xw


excel_file = 'excel_file.xlsx'

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb1 = xw.Book(excel_file)
    ws1 = wb1.sheets['Sheet3']

    ws1.copy(before=wb1.sheets(1), name="NewSheet")

    wb1.save(excel_file)
```

Example 2 copy sheet to another workbook

```
import xlwings as xw


excel_file1 = 'excel_file.xlsx'
excel_file2 = 'new_excel_file.xlsx'


with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb1 = xw.Book(excel_file1)
    wb2 = xw.Book(excel_file2)
    ws1 = wb1.sheets['Sheet3']

    ws1.copy(before=wb2.sheets(1), name="NewSheet")

    wb2.save(excel_file2)
```